# JavaScript: how much is textarea scrolled?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to know how much is the `<textarea>` or `<div style="overflow:scroll">` scrolled. Vertically or horizontally. I expect an answer like this:

```
function getElementVerticalScroll(el){
      return integer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filled in the blank space of your function:

```
function getElementVerticalScroll(el){
      return el.scrollTop;
}
function getElementHorizontalScroll(el){
      return el.scrollLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bring in a library, have a look at the `scrollTop` property of the element: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/GXGHB/2/.

```
textarea.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I think `$(element).scrollTop();` should do the vertically-lookup. And `scrollLeft` for horizontal.